# Is it ok to edit a question into something complete different?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

Is it possible to edit a question that is not answered into a question that has a completely different meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, however edits that materially change the meaning are better suited to new questions entirely.

Here are some community resources:

[The editing privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

[How editing works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Answer (score 2):

[The other answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1115/10) addresses the question text, "Is it possible...."

As to the title question, "Is it ok..." the answer is **[absolutely not](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1123/10)!**

Comment: Excellent point!